# Загрузить первый килобайт файла

Tags: c#

Написать на C#. Файл на компьютере очень большой, а в программу надо загрузить первый килобайт.

Comment: Откуда загрузить? Куда загрузить? Конкретизируйте вопрос

Comment: на компьютере есть файл надо первые 1024 байт загрузить в программу, что непонятного? Да и ответ уже дан

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как-то так, например:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)) {
    fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```